# quotient of moduli of vector bundles on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X:=SU_C(r,L)$ is the moduli of semistable bundles of rank $r$ and $det=L$.
Then the group of $r$-torsion points ($=J(C)_r$) act on this moduli space.
We know that $X$ is also moduli of $SL_r$-bundles and the full quotient $X/J(C)_r$ is the moduli of $PGL_r$-bundles.

Suppose $K$ is any subgroup of $J(C)_r$. Then is the quotient $X/K$ also a moduli space ?

thank..

Answer (score 2):

Everything is a moduli space.  It sounds to me like you want to ask a slightly more precise question: for every subgroup $K\subset J(C)_r$, does there exist a subgroup $A\subset Z(SL_r)$ such that $X/K$ is the moduli space of principal $SL_r/A$-bundles on $C$.  This cannot be true just by counting the number of subgroups of $J(C)_r$ (many if the genus is large) versus the number of subgroups of $Z(SL_r)$ (the Euler phi function of $r$, independent of the genus).